# Read HDF files into MATLAB from a list.dat file containing the names of these files

Tags: list, matlab, hdfs

I have a list.dat file that contains the names, in order, of about 1000 hdf files. I need to read these into MATLAB one by one in order and input the data contained in them into a matrix. How do I make MATLAB read in the hdf files? I know how to make MATLAB read one file, but when it's only the filenames in a list (in the same directory as the actual files), I don't know how to make it read in the variable.

Here's what I have so far:

```
% Read in sea ice concentrations
 % AMSR-E data format: 'asi-s6250-20110101-v5.hdf'; 
 % AMSR2 data format: 'asi-AMSR2-s6250-20120724-v5.hdf';
 % SSMI data format: 'asi-SSMIS17-s6250-20111001-v5.hdf';
fname = 'list.dat';
data = double(hdfread(fname, 'ASI Ice Concentration'));
```

This currently does not work. It throws an error saying,

??? Error using ==> hdfquickinfo>findInsideVgroup at 156
HDF file '/home/AMSR_SeaIceData_Antarctic/list.dat' may be invalid or corrupt.

Error in ==> hdfquickinfo at 34
    [found, hinfo] = findInsideVgroup ( filename, dataname );

Error in ==> hdfread>dataSetInfo at 363
    hinfo = hdfquickinfo(filename,dataname);

Error in ==> hdfread at 210
[hinfo,subsets] = dataSetInfo(varargin{:});

The code works when I just put in the actual filename of the hdf file for fnames.

Thanks.

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html
Then loop over the resulting matrix

Comment: I tried: 
        fnames = load ('list.dat', '-hdf', 'ASI Ice Concentration');
It's saying there's an unknown command option.

Comment: A text file is not an hdf file. You said `list.dat` is a text file. You may want to use functions that can read in text files. My link has an overview of functions and one column reads "Supports Nonnumeric Data?" which is probably of interest